# x is not a function in one file, but it works in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function called send() in one file called helpers.js defined like this:

```
module.exports = {
  send: function (param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    //does something
  }
}
```

I have two additional files where I am trying to use this function from so i have imported the file like this in both of the files:

```
helpers             = require("../modules/helpers"),
```

In one of the files, I can access the `helpers.send(param1, param2, param3)` function without issues, but in the other file I always get `helpers.send is not a function`.

Why is it that I can only access the `send()` function from one file and not the other?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: different folder locations...so '../modules/helpers' is valid?

Comment: In the file that’s not working, what is helper and helper.send? (Either by adding a breakpoint or console.log)

Comment: Both files are in the same folder so the path should work, identical require statements in both as well.

Comment: It may be the case that you are overwriting `send` function in one of the files. If you do something like `helpers.send = null` then it will throw that error.

Comment: can you include all your code here? perhaps it is something not related to module loading

Comment: @stealththeninja if I console the helpers I get {}

Comment: @MatusDubrava unfortunately I'm not overriding the helpers.send anywhere.

Comment: @ABOS I've added my exact code, does that help?

Comment: what is the second file requiring helpers? and which one failed ?

Comment: @ABOS I think I've figured it out. File 1 references the helpers file and the helpers references the File 1 while File 2 references helpers but helpers doesn't reference File 2. That is why File 2 works. I guess I can remove the require and it will work. Thanks for the help, your questions led me to figure it out. If you convert to an answer I can mark it.

Comment: @user2573690, great!